# What were the Einzberns planning to do once Kiritsugu won the war?

Tags: fate-zero

The Einzberns hire Kiritsugu. Some random mage hunter guy.

As far as I'm concerned, the Einzberns pretend to use the Grail to restore the Third Magic thing.

But, if Kiritsugu uses the Grail for his wish (the world peace thing), won't the Grail vanish?

So the question is, what were the Einzberns planning to do once Kiritsugu won the war? Don't they need the Grail to get the Third Magic thing?

Answer (score 2):

This spoils Fate/Stay Night, especially the Heaven's Feel route.

> There are actually two Grails. The Greater Grail that was created by the three mage families, the one that facilitates the war and is the one that would be used to "perform" the Third Magic. The Lesser one is the one that manifests at end of the war and does the wish magic. Most of the power that gets accumulated from heroic spirits goes to Greater Grail, while Lesser Grail gets only a small fraction for doing actual wish. Simply said, the whole "unlimited wish" from Lesser Grail is a plain lie.

Comment: So the Einzbern knew that Kiritsugu would not be able to get his wish granted and thus they knew they could secure the Greater Grail without problem (assuming Kiritsugu wouldn't think of destroying the grail)?